# Impedance adaptation for two frequencies

Tags: rf, impedance, impedance-matching, trace

I just received my first custom RF board that use 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz with a diplexer.

Unfortunately, it appears that the used PCB stack-up wasn't really what I expected so my traces are not 50 Ω, but more around 38 Ω and I suspect this is why my communication is not working perfectly.

The designed RF path is described on the following picture:

[image]

Because the adaptation filter is near the antenna, it needs to work for both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. However, using various online calculators, I found different values for those two frequencies. What would you do to correct this issue? Can I expect some okay(ish) result if I use values in between the proposed ones?

For some details, I found that I need L = 1.4 nH and C = 730 nF for 2.4 GHz and L = 650 pH and C = 350 fF for 5 GHz (is C even necessary in this case?).

Do you think that there is a way to make some changes that would correct my issue, or will I be forced to chose one of the two frequencies (or even worse, will I be forced to redo some boards)?

Also, I wanted your advice about what can I do to avoid this for next production (except asking for controlled impedance). Would it be useful to add dedicated adaptation filter for each frequency before for the diplexer?

Comment: Unless your time has no value, redoing the boards and paying for controlled impedance is probably the cheapest/fastest/lowest-risk way to solve this problem. Why are you trying to avoid this solution? How are you going to add an adaption filter without redoing the board or fabbing a new board for the filter? How confident are you that the Z0 mismatch is the whole problem (FYI you haven't shared enough information with us for us to be able to confirm/reject this hypothesis)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, to be honest, I'm trying to avoid having to pay for another production.
In your opinion, there is no way to mitigate this issue using the already present adaptation filter ?
Also I suspect this is the issue as I mostly re-used an existing design that works well on another board. As the pinout and the firmware are the same, it was my last guess about what could cause some communication issue.